# Vue.js 2 - Array change detection

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, splice

Here's a simplified version of my code :

```
    <template>

        /* ---------------------------------------------------------- 
         *  Displays a list of templates, @click, select the template
        /* ----------------------------------------------------------
        <ul>
            <li 
                v-for="form in forms.forms" 
                @click="selectTemplate(form)" 
                :key="form.id" 
                :class="{selected: templateSelected == form}">
                <h4>{{ form.name }}</h4>
                <p>{{ form.description }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

        /* -------------------------------------------------------- 
         *  Displays the "Editable fields" of the selected template
        /* --------------------------------------------------------
        
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(editableField, index) in editableFields" :key="editableField.id">                                       
            <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="appfield appfield-block data-to-document" 
                    :id="'item_'+index" 
                    :name="editableField.tag" 
                    v-model="editableField.value">
        </div>                    
    </template>
            
    <script> 
        export default {                        
            data: function () {
                return {
                    editableFields: [],
                }
            },
            methods: {
                selectTemplate: function (form) {

                    /* ------------------ 
                    *  My problem is here
                    */ ------------------

                    for (let i = 0; i < form.editable_fields.length; i++) {                                         
                        this.editableFields.push(form.editable_fields[i]);              
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Basically I want to update the array EditableFields each time the user clicks on a template. My problem is that Vuejs does not update the display because the detection is not triggered. I've read the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) which advise to either $set the array or use Array instance methods only such as splice and push.

The code above (with push) **works** but the array is never emptied and therefore, "editable fields" keep pilling up, which is not a behavior I desire.

In order to empty the array before filling it again with fresh data, I tried several things with no luck :

```
this.editableFields.splice(0, this.editableFields.length);

for (let i = 0; i < form.editable_fields.length; i++) {
    this.editableFields.push(form.editable_fields[i]);                   
}
```

==> Does not update the display

```
for (let i = 0; i < form.editable_fields.length; i++) {                 
    this.$set(this.editableFields, i, form.editable_fields[i]);
}
```

==> Does not update the display

```
this.editableFields = form.editable_fields;
```

==> Does not update the display

Something I haven't tried yet is setting a whole new array with the fresh data but I can't understand how I can put that in place since I want the user to be able to click (and change the template selection) more than once.

I banged my head on that problem for a few hours now, I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance :) !

Answer (score 1):

I've got no problem using splice + push. The reactivity should be triggered normally as described in the link you provided.

See my code sample:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      forms: {
        forms: [{
            id: 'form1',
            editable_fields: [{
                id: 'form1_field1',
                value: 'form1_field1_value'
              },
              {
                id: 'form1_field2',
                value: 'form1_field2_value'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 'form2',
            editable_fields: [{
                id: 'form2_field1',
                value: 'form2_field1_value'
              },
              {
                id: 'form2_field2',
                value: 'form2_field2_value'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      editableFields: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectTemplate(form) {
      this.editableFields.splice(0, this.editableFields.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < form.editable_fields.length; i++) {
        this.editableFields.push(form.editable_fields[i]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="form in forms.forms" 
            @click="selectTemplate(form)" 
            :key="form.id">
            <h4>{{ form.id }}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="form-group"
        v-for="(editableField, index) in editableFields"
        :key="editableField.id">
            {{ editableField.id }}:
        <input type="text" v-model="editableField.value">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right, an unrelated part of my code was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... Another remote part of the code was in fact, causing the problem.

For future reference, this solution is the correct one :

```
this.editableFields.splice(0, this.editableFields.length);

for (let i = 0; i < form.editable_fields.length; i++) {
    this.editableFields.push(form.editable_fields[i]);                   
}
```

Using only Array instance methods is the way to go with Vuejs.

Comment: You can also do `this.editableFields = [ ]` which sets back the array to an empty one

Comment: Thanks ! This is shorter !